# "The Tor Browser Bundle should not be run as root" Why?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ubuntu

I tried to run Tor browser bundle as a root but it it didn't start and I got the above quoted error message. I'm not sure why? and I'm also wondering if there is away to make that possible.

Thanks,

Comment: To fix it Follow the steps below ***1. start-tor-browser.desktop -h*** ***2. start-tor-browser.desktop --verbose*** you'll get some error and warning according to the system requirement, **configure** it then run the tor app . *its true tor can't open in roo*t, u have to create a *new user* .

Comment: This doesn't seem add anything extra to the previous answers. Can you explain what the two commands do? If the `--verbose` command is just being used to generate some console logs, do these logs add anything to the error the user is already seeing?

Answer (score 14):

**Short Answer**:

There is no advantage to using TBB as root, but there are significant risks.

**Longer Answer:**

It is a generally accepted practice that userland applications (ie: application that are not system services) should not be run using a privileged account. This is to help ensure integrity and isolation of potentially harmful applications from core system resources.

A browser in particular is a high value target for adversaries as browsers interact with unknown third parties. Despite the Firefox and TBB developers' best efforts, it is possible that there may be vulnerabilities in TBB. If an attacker took control of a system via TBB, the damage could be much much worse if TBB was being run as a superuser.

Answer (score 6):

Use the text editor and open the `start-tor-browser` script file. Search for the word *root*, you will see these lines:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
    complain "The Tor Browser Bundle should not be run as root.  Exiting."
    exit 1
fi
```

Remove or comment out the `exit 1` command.

Comment: I'd recommend against doing this.  Just set up a non-root account.

Comment: A warning should be put at the beginning of this answer to warn users against doing this.

Comment: @Yuriko: The code already has the warning in it. Removing it now anyway. I do EVERYTHING as root. Now going to fix VLC.

Comment: This is particularly useful for Kali users

Comment: thank you very much it works! and in my case the file is inside /root/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me; I removed these lines but the warning is still shown. Is there more than one instance where this "I refuse to be started" check is used? [Edit: Interesting. Seems as if .Xauthority in the home directory is also checked; I moved it to try if that made a difference and indeed it does. Not sure if this is helpful to anyone else, but at the least now the tor browser started. My original use case was to simply write a comment on a webforum without getting sniff-traced back, so this was a much faster way to solve that issue than "doing it the right way".]